# Is there a Pyhon module to read from Oracle and Split into multiple excel files with less memory usage based on column?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, xlsxwriter

I am trying to split an oracle table based on values in a column (Hospital Names). The data set is ~3 Mil rows across 66 columns. I'm trying to write data for 1 hospital from 3 different table into 1 excel workbook in 3 different sheets.

I have a running code which worked for ~700K rows but the new set is too large and I run into memory problems. I tried to modify my code to hit the database each time for a hospital name using a for loop. But I get xlsx error of closing it explicitly.

```
import cx_Oracle
import getpass
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\HN\1"

p = getpass.getpass()

# Connecting to Oracle
myusername = 'CN138609'

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('oflc1exa03p-vip.centene.com', '1521', service_name='IGX_APP_P')

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=myusername, password=p, dsn=dsn_tns)

sql_4 = "select distinct hospital_name from HN_Hosp_Records"


df4 = pd.read_sql(sql_4,conn)



hospital_name = list(df4['HOSPITAL_NAME'])

for x in hospital_name:
    hosp_name = {"hosp" : x}
    sql_1 = "select * from HN_Hosp_Records where hospital_name = :hosp"
    sql_2 = "select * from HN_CAP_Claims_Not_In_DHCS where hospital_name = :hosp"
    sql_3 = "select * from HN_Denied_Claims where hospital_name = :hosp"

    df1 = pd.read_sql(sql_1,conn,params=hosp_name)
    df2 = pd.read_sql(sql_2,conn,params=hosp_name)
    df3 = pd.read_sql(sql_3,conn,params=hosp_name)

    df_dhcs = df1.loc[df1['HOSPITAL_NAME'] == x]
    df_dw = df2.loc[df2['HOSPITAL_NAME'] == x]
    df_denied = df3.loc[df3['HOSPITAL_NAME'] == x]
    # Create a new excel workbook
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path + x + "_HNT_P2_REC_05062019.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
    df_dhcs.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DHCS")
    df_dw.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Not In DHCS")
    df_denied.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Denied")
    writer.close()
```

Here is the warning/error I'm getting. The code doesn't stop but no file is being output:

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 153, in **del**
    raise Exception("Exception caught in workbook destructor. "
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. instead of binding variable using %s was the trick.